Error during configuration of IBM case manager for IBM BAW
I have installed IBM BAW workflow center for testing the product.
I am getting the following error during setting up case manager while executing the following script. And I am connected to the wsadmin as shown below.
how I connected to wsadmin:
wsadmin.bat -lang jython -user dep_admin -password Admin_123 -host localhost -port 8879

wsadmin command:
wsadmin>print AdminTask.createObjectStoreForContent(['-clusterName', 'SingleCluster','-PEWorkflowSystemAdminGroup', 'CaseAdmin','-creationUser','dep_admin','-password','Admin_123'])

Error:
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminTask.createObjectStoreForContent(['-clusterName', 'SingleCluster','-PEWorkflowSystemAdminGroup', 'CaseAdmin','-creationUser','dep_admin','-password','Admin_123'])"; exception information:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.ibm.bpm.config.spi.ConfigurationSpi.getAuthenticationAliasName() requires a non-null deploymentTarget when called on the deployment manager

I am following the documentation and currently I am performing the following steps shown in the link:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/baw/24.x?topic=scripting-createobjectstoreforcontent
